# Drupal : Accessing "Json Page" type content as headless API with "JSON:API" module

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, json-api, headless-cms

I've created a ***JSON Page*** type content on Drupal 8/9/10 as below that has ***JSON Config*** as below.
I used this field to build the headless content that needs to exposed to UI Apps.

[image]

I want to expose this as headless content API ( JSON Configuration alone ) . But when I access this JSON Page with ***JSON API*** module, I get ***JSON Config*** of this page as another data field [*field_json_config*] with string value  as below.

[image]

Is there a way to expose this ***JSON Config*** as API as this will be the actual content API .

I even created JSON Field and set that as field type, still the API gives string.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason you are not adding fields for each item in the json? Adding json directly sort of defeats the purpose of a CMS.

Comment: Raw json just a view.  JSON is composed with the field view in tree structure  . Content editors will use same field editor